# Vue router to serve a json file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I need to render/serve a json file using vue router for https://mysite/apple-app-site-association. I don't use webpack and the app is hosted as azure static web app. I want to return content-type as application/json as well. I'm using Vue 2.6. How do I do this?

Comment: pls. show your code so far. Is the file static?

Comment: The file is static. I don't have any code to show as I'm stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: Rendering and serving are two different things. I think you just meant "serve" the file.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend a little on how you are serving your web pages on Azure but I did the following on AWS, which has virtually nothing to do with Vue.

1. Created a new folder in my public folder
2. Added the json file to the new folder
3. Deployed my app (which creates the folder on the AWS host and puts the JSON file in it)
4. Configured my host to override/bypass my Vue SPA and serve the JSON file for a particular path (in my case AWS cloudfront).

I could have manually added the JSON folder and file to my cloud host and configured it to serve the JSON but I wanted an automatic deployment.  Sorry I can't help on Azure but I hope there are similar concepts as cloudfront on AWS.